# Material Design Body 1 vs Body 2

Tags: fonts, material-design, typography

In [Material Design Typography](https://material.io/design/typography) there is a `Body 1` and `Body 2`.

[image]

While one can easily see the differences between them - `Body 1` has a slightly larger font size and letter spacing - I am wondering when one would use `Body 1` and when one would use `Body 2`.

I could not find any hints on that and why there are two body fonts. Can anyone explain that? Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark choosing the right font is a part of the app development, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The difference in font sizes is more relevant for different languages ie 14px for Chinese alphabet. Nonetheless it might just be an issue of consistency for the English alphabet though.

Source: https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/#typography